# Column change after Form-Request

Tags: google-apps-script, laravel-formrequest

I have following situation with my google sheet.
Sometimes the Sheet changes a prefilled header of a column, which is created by a form request.
I collect the Email addresses from the Form in a Sheet. So the Sheets makes a prefilled column namend "Email Address".
The collected data is then copied(with a script) to an Overview-Sheet. But it is already happend that my script does not work because, I dont know why, the header of the column "Email Address" is changed to "Email address". The script is with the ....setValue(e.namedValues["Email Address"]) searching for the right entry to copy it to the Overview. But the script can't find the right value if the name is changed to "Email address".

Does someone know why this column changes sometimes?

There is a trigger "on form submit" to copy the data to the Overview. So everytime someone is filling up the form, the script copies the data to the Overview-Sheet.

Thank you for help

Jonas

**UPDATE**:

Hello Jose,

The main issue is, that the Spreadsheet changes the Column C [image]

to "Email address" with no reason.

I compare the "Email Address" with a entry from a Google Form request called "line Manager E-mail Address" (is filled from the person who makes a request via Form)

the code is

```
function incorrectSupervisor(e) {


      if (e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString() == e.namedValues["Line Manager E-Mail Address"].toString()) {
        information.ErrorMessage = " The requester cannot be the line manager. Please provide the E-Mail address of your line manager"
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

But if the name in column C is changed the compare function does not work, because the capital A from ["Email Address"] is changed to a small "a" (["Email address"]). The code is triggerd with On-Form-Submit.

so my question is: How is it possible that the Spreadsheeds changes the Name of the header from column c without any manual changes?

Thanks

Jonas

Comment: Can you please specify in a more specific way (sharing Spreadsheet, images or well-formatted code) which is the current issue or question?

Comment: Spreadsheet won't make any changes to your sheets unless you explicitly change it programmatically through Apps Script or the cell or range is protected. By seeing the information provided there's nothing much we can do. This is not recommended but I understand your case is specific so it'd be helpful if you shared the Spreadsheet without sensitive data or share another Spreadsheet as "example" which shares similarities.